# how to configure bigram model in gensim to include custom bigrams?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

Suppose I have data to be trained in sentence_stream

```
phrases = Phrases(sentence_stream)
bigram_model = Phraser(phrases)
```

Now, If I try my bigram_model on some test data and check the output

```
sent = [u'the', u'mayor', u'of', u'new', u'york', u'was', u'there']
print(bigram_model[sent])
[u'the', u'mayor', u'of', u'new_york', u'was', u'there']
```

Now, Suppose If want to add custom bigrams like the_mayor in my bigram_model so that the output should contain

```
[u'the_mayor', u'of', u'new_york', u'was', u'there']
```

Any suggestions on how to configure the bigram_model?